# Creating a function out of a dataframe with a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, linear-regression, plyr

I have several variables in my dataframe (e.g.: a, b, c, d) and I'm obtaining by season linear model parameters (Intercept, Slope and rSquared) through this code (Example for variable a):

```
lm_results_season_a<- ddply(dataframe1, "Season", function(x) {
  model <- summary(lm(y ~ a, data = x))
  Intercept<- model$coefficients[1,1]
  Slope<- model$coefficients[2,1]
  rSquared <- model$r.squared
  data.frame(Intercept, Slope, rSquared)
})
```

My problem is that I have too many variables, and repeat this code again for each variable takes a lot of space.
For example, I would have to write the same code for variable b

```
lm_results_season_b<- ddply(dataframe1, "Season", function(x) {
  model <- summary(lm(y ~ b, data = x))
  Intercept<- model$coefficients[1,1]
  Slope<- model$coefficients[2,1]
  rSquared <- model$r.squared
  data.frame(Intercept, Slope, rSquared)
})
```

and keep repeating the same code for the rest of the variables. So I tried to create a function in which I don't have to repeat all this code again, but just to call a function that can make all the calculations and give me the dataframe I am looking for.
I tried this code in which I define the variables before, and then just add them to the function:

```
variable1 <- dataframe1$y
variable2 <- dataframe1$a

LM_coef <- function(data, variable1, variable2){
  lm_results_season<- ddply(data, "Season", function(x) {
    model <- summary(lm(variable1 ~ variable2, data = x))
    Intercept<- model$coefficients[1,1]
    Slope<- model$coefficients[2,1]
    rSquared <- model$r.squared
    data.frame(Intercept,Slope, rSquared)
  })   
  return(lm_results_season)
}
```

But this is not working as I wanted. Instead of giving me the linear regression parameters by Season for the variable "a", it is just giving me the linear regression parameters just for the variable "a" as a whole, and not by season.

Any idea on what's happening in the function or how to modify this function?

Comment: Maybe pass the formula directly `LM_coef <- function(data, formula){
  lm_results_season<- ddply(data, "Season", function(x) {
    model <- summary(lm(formula = formula, data = x)) ;
    ....
  }) ;  
  return(lm_results_season)
} ;

LM_coef(data = dataframe1, formula = y ~ a)`

Comment: I tried but it's still giving me the same output as the function I posted. Thanks for your time tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you bound to the `plyr` package? Otherwise, you can use the more advanced and up-to-date `purrr` package, always from the `tidyverse` world.

Here we can create a function where we insert the dataframe `data`, the two variables for the linear model `variable1` and `variable2`, and the splitting column `split_var` (in your case "Season").

```
LM_coef <- function(data, variable1, variable2, split_var){
  require(purrr)
  
  data %>%
    split(.[[split_var]]) %>%
    map(~summary(lm(eval(as.name(variable1)) ~ eval(as.name(variable2)), data = .x))) %>%
    map_dfr(~cbind(as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(coef(.)[1:2,1]))), .$r.squared), .id = split_var) %>% 
    setNames(c(split_var, "Intercept", "Slope", "rSquared"))
}
```

---

#### Example

Using the `mtcars` dataset, we can do

```
LM_coef(mtcars, "hp", "mpg", "cyl")
```

in order to obtain

```
#   cyl Intercept     Slope   rSquared
# 1   4  147.4315 -2.430092 0.27405583
# 2   6  164.1564 -2.120802 0.01614624
# 3   8  294.4974 -5.647887 0.08044919
```

which is equal to what you would obtain from your initial function `lm_results_season_a`.